# Unit3D Multiplayer breaks Vive Controller

Tags: unity-game-engine, htc-vive

I've got a couple games that I programmed in Unity3D, making use of an HTC Vive.  I then created a lobby that I could use the controllers to teleport around in, by using the VR Interaction system. (Point the controller, and press the touch pad.  It lights up an arc and a landing spot.  Let go of the touchpad and you're moved.)

Then I made the mistake of "improving" things by adding the NetworkManager and NetworkManagerHUD.

Now, while I can see the controllers moving around, and it even shows me where I'm touching the touchpad, the teleport arc doesn't show up and I'm not able to teleport.  Within my game, I'm no longer able to grab and hold anything with the trigger button.

I've gone through the tutorials several times, and I'm positive I have this set just like the manual says.  Are the local controllers supposed to break when you add networked multiplayer?